# What can be said about $f(A)$ provided $f$ is a linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Given question states:

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ be  a linear map and $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}/|x|\leq 1,|y|\le 1\}$ then:

(a) $f(A)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$

(b)$f(A)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R^3}$

(c) $f(A)$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$

(d) $f(A)$ is a unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$

I am not getting how to deal with this question. What I know is $f$ is a linear map and the set $A$ is compact and is clearly path connected so is connected too.

But unable to conclude any thing about $f(A)$.

If $f$ was given continuous, then could have said being image of compact and connected, $f(A)$ is also connected and compact.

But here $f$ is given linear, I have no idea about how to conclude for $f(A)$.

Please hint me how can I use linearity of map here...or any results abouts linear function.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For a start, linear maps are continuous.